# Is there a way to enable controls in video player playing youtube videos flutter web

Tags: flutter, youtube, video-player, youtubeplayer

I am making a page to show a lot of videos from youtube and am using the [ext_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_video_player) in flutter web. But now I want to enable show controls. I also want it to be possible for an app. I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216557/how-to-show-playback-controls-by-default-for-video-player-plugin-flutter-web) stack over flow post. But the chewie player says that it needs a video controller player from video_player not ext_video_player. Is there any other way to do this so that it works both for flutter web and app and also allows youtube videos. the youtube player plugin is not a choice because of some reasons.I have been unable to make it for even one. Code using rn

```
class videoBox2 extends StatefulWidget {
  String Video;
  videoBox2(this.Video);
  @override
  _videoBox2State createState() => _videoBox2State(Video);
}

class _videoBox2State extends State<videoBox2> {
  String Video;
  bool error = false;
  _videoBox2State(this.Video);
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  @override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      Video,
    );

    _controller.initialize().then((value) {
      setState(() {
      });
    });
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.value.hasError) {
        setState(() {
          error = true;
          print(Video);
        });
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return error?Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))
        ),
        child: Image(fit:BoxFit.cover,image:NetworkImage("https://hiapseng-thailand.com/wp-content/themes/skywalker/facilities/video-placeholder.jpg"))
    ):GestureDetector(
        onTap:(){
          _controller.value.isPlaying?
          _controller.pause()
              :_controller.play();
        },
        child: Container(
          width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))
          ),
          child:  VideoPlayer(_controller),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I finally did was a very simple technique. I imported the chewie video player and opened its files from the dart plugins inside the external libraries. Then I changed all the video_player/video_player.dart to ext_video_player/ext_video_player.dart. This worked as ext_video_player is just an extension of video player

**Warning :- This will affect all your projects using chewie player. Make this change, build the project, and then remove the changes**

So what you do is go to the external libraries folder, then open Dart Packages, and scroll down to the folder chewie-0.12.0 (Or whatever package you are using)\

Then open the source folder, and go to these files :-\

1. chewie_player.dart
2. cupertino_controls.dart
3. cupertino_progress_bar.dart
4. material_controls.dart
5. material_progress_bar.dart
6. player_with_controls.dart\

Now in all these files, you have to scroll to the top and find this line

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
```

And replace it with

```
import 'package:ext_video_player/ext_video_player.dart';
```

Do remember to import the [ext_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_video_player) package in the pubspec.yaml. Read the instruction for this package but basically you can provide a youtube url is the
`VideoPlayer.network()`
thing. I hope this solves your problem. You can also use web-views for apps or iframes for website if you wish though its not recommended

Comment: I have updated the answer and explained what I have done. Does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Dart Packages will be deleted when running `flutter clean`, using @Siddharth answer, I fork Chewie and edit according to @Siddharth answer (change video_player to ext_video_player).

You can change your Chewie to my git in the pubspec.yaml:

```
  chewie:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/azhar-rafiq/chewie/
```